# How to "ignore" username and password prompt in net use

Tags: linux, windows, samba, batch, windows-command-prompt

I have at the moment a logon.cmd script, that I'm using to map network drives to the users profile. It looks like this:

```
::Onboarding
net use m: /delete
net use m: \\BOB\onboarding 
::Bookings
net use n: /delete
net use n: \\BOB\bookings 

::Accounts
net use j: /delete
net use j: \\BOB\accounts
```

It works fine up until it gets up to a folder that the current user cannot access, it then asks for a username and password instead of erroring and continuing.

Notes: This very script used to work on another Samba PDC network, but I've moved it over to another server (Still Samba PDC) and now its breaking.

**Is there anyway for it to ignore the username/password prompt and just continue?**

Comment: Gotta ask - Why are you running a script to map drives that the user may not have a access to?

Comment: Logon.cmd is the only script that can be ran during boot, and it has no way of knowing who should have access to what, so, it has to try to map everything otherwise it would get skipped

Comment: I don't use Samba, so I'm not fully familiar with it, but are you saying that all users must have the same script? Can't you set a logon script on a per-user basis?

Comment: Unfortunately no :/, Samba is a lot more basic than your normal AD PDC, you have one script for everyone on logon.

Comment: And this is a prime example of why it's usually not a good idea to try and replace Active Directory with something that isn't Active Directory.

Comment: This is very true MDMarra, but $0 software budget causes certain restrictions :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was never able to find a finite solution to the problem. But a usable (but very hacky and unclean) work around is using this command:

```
::Helpdesk
copy /Y NUL "\\BOB\helpdesk\.writable"
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 ( 
    del \\BOB\helpdesk\.writable
    GOTO:ALLOWEDHELPDESK
 ) 

GOTO:SECT2
:ALLOWEDHELPDESK
net use k: /delete
net use k: \\BOB\helpdesk 
:SECT2

::Onboarding
copy /Y NUL "\\BOB\onboarding\.writable" 
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 ( 
    del \\BOB\onboarding\.writable
    GOTO:ALLOWEDONBOARDING
 ) 

GOTO:SECT3
:ALLOWEDONBOARDING
net use m: /delete
net use m: \\BOB\onboarding 
:SECT3

::Etc,etc,etc
```

Basic explanation:
It checks to see if a folder is writeable first by coping a blank file .writable, if it succeeds it executes the command, if it fails it skips the command and continues on.

This is purely a workaround....

Comment: Hey @Mattisdada, I'm adding an answer that extends yours. Maybe a community wiki would make sense here; I'm not sure. Thanks for posting question/answer. Your solution was the best fix I could find for my problem and I just hope my answer can add a little value.

Answer (score 2):

Extending Mattisdada's answer, this script will make it a bit easier to modify any drive mappings by simply adding, deleting or changing the `mapDrive` function calls. Additionally, this function checks for read access by calling `DIR` (instead of writing the temp file) and maps accordingly:

```
@ECHO off

setlocal
set SHARE=BOB
CALL:mapDrive K: helpdesk
CALL:mapDrive M: onboarding
CALL:mapDrive Z: watercooler
endlocal

net use
ECHO Mapping Complete. Thank You.
PAUSE&GOTO:EOF

:mapDrive
DIR \\%SHARE%\%~2 > nul 2>&1
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 ( 
    net use %~1 /DELETE > nul 2>&1
    net use %~1 \\%SHARE%\%~2
)
GOTO:eof
```

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have figured this out on my end, I just enter a password as an argument of net use, after the folder to be mapped, as below:

..
net use t: \BOB\helpdesk password /PERSISTENT:NO

not exactly sure why it works, as its not the right password for the user but it seems to map it anyway if the user has access and just throw an access denied if no access to drive and moves on :)

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

net use t: \BOB\helpdesk password /PERSISTENT:NO

seems to have worked but fails after recent updates.

if EXIST \BOB\helpdesk net use t: \BOB\helpdesk /PERSISTENT:NO

is a solution that keeps working for me. It skips if the user does not have sufficient access rights(works for network shares).

Comment: i would use if NOT exist to run it only in case its not existing else your exmaple runs only if its exists